# Shallow Well - want to use for yard watering

Tags: well

What do I need to use my shallow well to water my garden?
I do have electricity available and a hand pump. Thanks

Comment: The question is very broad, you could use the hand pump, or you could purchase a shallow well pump or a jet pump, but more information would need to be added like water depth, diameter of the well, the type of watering you want to do “flood” where there are no restrictions on the line or sprinklers then pressure switches and tanks would be needed. So please more info.

Comment: It would really know what kind of hand pump you have. There are many.